# Play from Shoutcast Url in android

Tags: android, shoutcast

I am developing an Application that needs to play Radio from Shout cast. 
For API I have followed this [URL](http://wiki.winamp.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_Radio_Directory_API)

I am successful in getting a station ID with my developer ID.Now in the section " How To Tune Into A Station " they have guided how to tune to a particular station. I have followed that section and used this [URL](http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=175821)  in my android media player. But my media player plays nothing.

Please note my target SDK is 16 and Min SDK is 13. So I hope android version is not a problem.
Media player works fine if am using other URLs like:

- http://streamplus8.leonex.de:14910
- http://s2.voscast.com:7016/
- http://s8.voscast.com:7024/

So I guess there is no issue with my media player. I have already gone through the post that are available in SO. Please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        Button play,pause,stop;
        private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        private String out;
//      private String url = "http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=175821";
//      private String url = "http://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3";

        private String url1 = "http://streamplus8.leonex.de:14910";
        private String url2 ="http://s2.voscast.com:7016/";
        private String url3 ="http://s8.voscast.com:7024/";
        private String url4 ="http://s8.voscast.com:7020/";
        private String url5 ="http://s5.voscast.com:8216/";

        private boolean pauseState = false;
        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
                pd.setMessage("Loading your song....");
                play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
                pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);
                stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);

                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url2);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check your connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                    
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                                if(pauseState == true) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } else {
                        pd.show();
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                                pd.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                                pauseState = false;                            
                        }
                });
            pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                   
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                mediaPlayer.pause();
                                pauseState = true;                             
                        }
                });
            stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                    
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                mediaPlayer.stop();
//                              mediaPlayer.release();
                        }
                });


        }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. fine I finally figured out myself. Actually when I hit this [Url](http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=175821)  one .pls file is getting downloaded. The content of .pls file is something like this

```
[playlist]
numberofentries=1
File1=http://203.150.225.71:8000
Title1=(#1 - 10866/10000) COOLfahrenheit 93
Length1=-1
Version=2
```

I have to read this file and then parse this file to get the actual URL.Here it is

```
http://203.150.225.71:8000
```

Android media player is able to play this URL.

Comment: hi, i want to implement shoutcast api in my android and i use this link http://wiki.winamp.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_Radio_Directory_API but i not know how to get k=[Your Dev ID] for use this api in my app.

Comment: you have to register yourself to get the device id

Comment: I got this in file not the url
'[playlist]
numberofentries=0
Version=2'
How should I get it?

Comment: @SyamantakBasu try this repository https://github.com/sandeeprana011/shoutcast_android

Comment: Can you please let us know how did you parse this .pls file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to download .pls file so that i find other solution.
Finally, i got simple shoutcast streaming app. 
Try [this](https://github.com/cr5315/shoutcast-android). Just change streaming url in **StreamService.java**.

Comment: You have used the same url inside file there too :O

Comment: What do you mean? In StreamService.java, you just change your url to String url = "http://176.31.115.196:8214/";  you need to set url to mediaplayer datasource. That sample project will run with your stream url.

Comment: _176.31.115.196:8214_ Isn't this the url we get after downloading the file and read from it?

Comment: no. my solution is not read the file. Just play shoutcast server public url. you need to know your shoutcast steam server public url.

Comment: hello @BM, I have two stream url at server so it is not working , but i tried with ur url then it is working.. please help me!!

Comment: @BM how to get the shoutcast stream server public url?

Comment: @Harry.Naeem I got public url from streaming server hosting.